# Are there any issues with cleaning glasses with microfibre cloth on Shabbas?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, cleaning

Are there any issues with cleaning eyeglasses with microfibre cloth on Shabbas? I'm assuming the microfibre cloth only and no cleaning spray.

I'm assuming the glasses are prescription glasses and the dirt is just smudges or surface dirt.  One potential issue I considered was whether the cleaning of smudges and grease spots might involve smoothing, although that might be a bit far-fetched.

Comment: See [this](http://www.koltorah.org/ravj/Melabain.htm) webpage from Kol Torah on the prohibition of melabin (laundering). Also, [this](http://halachos.com/Halacha/hal_501_600.asp) page in note 536 seems to say it's OK to clean glasses on Shabbos.

Comment: tofeach a. m. lehatfiach?

Comment: Wow, I hope not -- my glasses are thick enough that I can't go an hour without smudging (that interferes with reading), I guess from my eyelashes.  And I can't wear contact lenses.

Answer (score 4):

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86469/9643) to a similar question answers your question, too:

> R. Moshe Stern ([Be'er Moshe 6:62](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=889&pgnum=322)) explicitly permits one to clean glasses on Shabbos, by both blowing on and wiping the glasses. He does not cite the Rema's ruling ([OC 319:17](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%98#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.99.D7.96)) in which he finds spitting [into the wind] liable of winnowing. R. Binyamin Zilber too ([Az Nidbaru vol. 13, no. 14](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=885&st=&pgnum=142)) permits the above case and likewise does not discuss winnowing. My assumption for their seeming disregard of the Rema is simply because, as noted by @mevaqesh, most authorities do not agree with this ruling.
>
> R. Ephraim Greenblatt ([Rivevos Ephraim 3:310](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1085&pgnum=121)) has a responsum where he too permits cleaning the glasses with a cloth and does not even mention an issue of winnowing. Same goes for Yalkut Yosef (Shabbos, vol. 2 pg. 88).